# Resource allocation- Matching

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

I've got a problem which I'm not sure can be solved by Linear Programming. Essentially there are 2 groups of people who are list their preference for one another and will be subsequently matchd. I'm writing an algorithm for this. Group A has upto 4 choices from Group B and vice versa.

In formulating a solution, I am currently assigning a cost to each combination of pairs. For example if Person 1 from Group A ranks Person 3 from Group B as his/her number 1 choice and vice versa, then the cost is minimal (Pair 1-3 cost: 0.01). Similarly, I would allot a cost to other pairs, devising an objective function which seeks to have pairings which minimize overall cost.

However, I do not see this being feasible because I don't know how to define my constraints and overall objective function. Reading online and from textbooks, I find resource allocation problems to be different from what I am trying to do.

Can I seek your advise on how to proceed?

Comment: This looks more like *maximum weight matching in bipartite graph* than like *linear programming* or any of its variants.  I won't go so far as to say you can't solve the problem with linear programming, but the other approach might be easier to start with.

Comment: Smells like [Stable Marriage Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem).

Comment: Yes, there are similarities to Stable marriage problem (SMP), but this problem is more general than that. The SMP solution displays a certain property (no mutual higher preferred matches for a pair) but the OP's problem is more generalized with minimum total cost desired.

Comment: I find the stable marriage problem good because of the definition of a stable pair. Also, implementing it avoids the hassle of developing  costs for pairings outlined in the LP solution below (I've explained why in the comment section). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be formulated as an **"[Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)."** As a canonical case, assignment problems are for assigning "jobs" to "machines." They can just as easily be used for Matching two sets.

Here's the formulation:
Two sets of people A and B

**Decision Variable Xij**

Let `Xij` be **1** if person i (ith person in set A) is matched with jth person in set B; **0** otherwise

Parameters:
Let `Cij` be the cost of pairing person `i` with person `j`

**Objective Function**: Minimize (Sum over i) (sum over j) `Cij * Xij`

**Constraints:**

Every Person i gets paired exactly once

`Sum over j Xij = 1 (for each i)`

Every Person j gets paired exactly once

`Sum over i Xij = 1 (for each j)`

Xij are Binary variables

`Xij = (0,1)`

The neat thing about Assignment problems is that the optimal pairings can be found using the fairly easy to understand ['Hungarian Method.'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) You can also use an LP/IP solver you have at your disposal.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I like this solution, however the problem with having a cost assigned to a pairing introduces subjectivity. How can one objectively ascertain the preference of person i for person j? There will be various factors that need to be considered. This gets more complicated as we explore, for example, person's i's 4 choice/person z's third choice (i.e. 4-3 pair)..how would that compare with a 2-3 pair, etc. This is the major block I face in adopting a LP solution. Thanks for the detailed explanation!